Concernings about proof of Stokes Theorem
The Theorem goes as follows.

Let $M$ be an oriented smooth $n$-manifold with boundary and $\omega\in\Omega_c^{n-1}(M)$ a differential $(n-1)$-form on $M$ with compact support. Then it holds that $$\int_M\mathrm{d}\omega = \int_{\partial M}\iota^*\omega,$$
where $\iota:\partial M\to M$ is the canonical inclusion map and $\partial M$ has the induced orientation.

Outline of the proof:

Special case: $M=\mathbb{H}^n$.
Special case: $M=\mathbb{R}^n$.
Special case: $M$ arbitrary oriented smooth $n$-manifold with boundary and $\omega\in\Omega_c^{n-1}(M)$ such that $\mathrm{supp}\,\omega\subset U$ for an oriented smooth chart $(U,\varphi)$ of $M$. This splits into two cases 3.1 and 3.2 where you first assume that $(U,\varphi)$ is a boundary-chart, i.e. $\varphi(U)\cap\partial\mathbb{H}^n\neq\emptyset$ and then assume that it's an interior chart.
General case as stated in the theorem.

In each of these cases, you basically use the previously proven case.
So case 1 and case 2 are quite done for me. I also know how to do case 4 and how to follow case 3.2 from case 3.1. My problems are with case 3.1:
Let $M$ be an oriented smooth $n$-manifold with boundary and $\omega\in\Omega_c^{n-1}(M)$ such that $\mathrm{supp}\,\omega\subset U$ for an oriented smooth boundary-chart $(U,\varphi)$ of $M$, i.e. $\varphi(U)\cap\partial\mathbb{H}^n\neq\emptyset$. We have
\begin{align*}
\int_M\mathrm{d}\omega &= \int_U\mathrm{d}\omega && \text{Since }\mathrm{supp}\,\omega\subset U \\
& = \int_{\varphi(U)}(\varphi^{-1})^*\mathrm{d}\omega && \text{Definition}\\
& = \int_{\mathbb{H}^n}\mathrm{d}\left((\varphi^{-1})^*\omega\right) && \text{Since }\mathrm{supp}\,(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega\subset\varphi(U)\subset\mathbb{H}^n\text{ and rules of d,}\,^*\\
& = \int_{\partial\mathbb{H}^n}\tilde{\iota}^*\left((\varphi^{-1})^*\omega\right) && \text{Case 1,}
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{\iota}:\partial\mathbb{H}^n\to\mathbb{H}^n,\,(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})\mapsto(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},0)$.
Now it's getting strange. We continue
\begin{align*}
\int_{\partial\mathbb{H}^n}\tilde{\iota}^*\left((\varphi^{-1})^*\omega\right) & \overset{???}{=}\int_{\varphi(\partial M\cap U)}(\varphi^{-1})^*(\iota^*\omega) && \text{?????????????????}\\
&= \int_{\partial M\cap U}\iota^*\omega && \text{Definition}\\
& = \int_{\partial M}\iota^*\omega && \text{Since }\mathrm{supp}\,\iota^*\omega\subset\partial M\cap U\subset\partial M.
\end{align*}
I marked the step where I am not quite sure what's happening, but I think that should be more or less true... Let's go through this in detail. So $\omega$ is a map $$\omega:U\supset\mathrm{supp}\,\omega\to\bigcup_{p\in\mathrm{supp}\,\omega}\Lambda^{n-1}(T_pM)$$, $\varphi$ is $\varphi:M\supset U\to\mathbb{H}^n$ with $\varphi(U)\cap\partial M\neq\emptyset$ and $$\varphi^{-1}:\mathbb{H}^n\supset\varphi(U)\to U\subset M$$ as well as $\iota:\partial M\to M$ and $\tilde{\iota}:\partial \mathbb{H}^n\to\mathbb{H}$. Then I think $$\iota^*\omega :\partial M\cap U\to\bigcup_{p\in\partial M\cap U}\Lambda^{n-1}(T_p\partial M)$$ or to be more precise $\iota^{-1}[\partial M\cap U]$ instead of $\partial M\cap U$ but that's just the same I would say and therefore $$(\varphi^{-1})^*(\iota^*\omega):\varphi(\partial M\cap U)\to\bigcup_{p\in\varphi(\partial M\cap U)}\Lambda^{-1}(T_p\mathbb{H}^n).$$ On the other hand we have $$(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega:\varphi(U)\to\bigcup_{p\in\varphi(U)}\Lambda^{n-1}(T_p\mathbb{H}^n)$$ and $$\tilde{\iota}^*\left((\varphi^{-1}\right)^*\omega):\tilde{\iota}^{-1}[\varphi(U)\cap\partial\mathbb{H}^n]\to\bigcup_{p\in \tilde{\iota}^{-1}[\varphi(U)\cap\partial\mathbb{H}^n]}\Lambda^{n-1}(T_p\partial\mathbb{H}^n),$$
where $\tilde{\iota}^{-1}[\varphi(U)\cap\partial\mathbb{H}^n]$ is the pre-image of $\varphi(U)\cap\partial\mathbb{H}$ under $\tilde{\iota}$. And I am not going to lie, this is kind of beyond the capabilities of my brain... Well, I can see that $$\tilde{\iota}^{-1}[\varphi(U)\cap\partial\mathbb{H}^n]=\varphi(\partial M\cap U)$$ holds. Just because it makes sense. And if I'm not mistaking I think I need that $${\varphi\bigr|}_{\partial M\cap U}:U\supset {\partial M\cap U}\to \varphi(U)\cap\partial\mathbb{H}^n$$ is somehow orientation preserving or something because otherwise I would never mention orientation in this case... And what's up with that $\tilde{\iota}^{-1}$ then...?

So as you can see, I am all over the place right now... The problem is that in almost every book they don't even consider the pullback by $\iota$ in this part of the proof, but I feel like it's essential, so I would like to cover it too... Maybe someone of you has a better understanding of this and would leave an answer. Thank you very much!

This is a combination of the general property $(fg)^{\ast}=g^{\ast}f^{\ast}$ of pullbacks and some notational sleight of hand. Indeed, when writing $\tilde{\iota}^{\ast}((\varphi^{-1})^{\ast}\omega)$, this does not strictly speaking make sense. First of all, $\omega$ is an $(n-1)$-form on $M$, $\varphi^{-1}\colon \varphi(U)\rightarrow U$ and $\tilde{\iota}\colon\partial\mathbb{H}^n\hookrightarrow\mathbb{H}$, so none of this matches up syntactically. To fix this, note ever since the very first equality you've written, we've actually replaced $\omega$ with its restriction $\omega\vert_U$ to the open subset $U\subseteq M$. This can be pulled back via $\varphi^{-1}$ to an $(n-1)$-form on on $\varphi(U)$, which in your $3$rd equality gets interpreted as an $(n-1)$-form on $\mathbb{H}^n$ (this is an 'extension by zero', possible since the form is compactly supported) and then this is pulled back via $\tilde{\iota}$ to an $(n-1)$-form on $\partial\mathbb{H}^n$.
However, since extension by zero does not change the integral, we could also instead first pull back $(\varphi^{-1})^{\ast}\omega$ via the restriction of $\tilde{\iota}$ to $\partial\mathbb{H}^n\cap\varphi(U)\hookrightarrow\varphi(U)$ and then extend via zero. Now, we note that the composite $\partial\mathbb{H}^n\cap\varphi(U)\hookrightarrow\varphi(U)\rightarrow U$ is the same thing as the composite $\partial\mathbb{H}^n\cap\varphi(U)\rightarrow\partial M\cap U\hookrightarrow U$, where the first map is a restriction of $\varphi^{-1}$ and the second map is a restriction of $\iota$. All the notational abuse in mind, we obtain the desired equality $\tilde{\iota}^{\ast}((\varphi^{-1})^{\ast}\omega)=(\varphi^{-1})^{\ast}(\iota^{\ast}\omega)$ (and the integral is then taken only over $\varphi(\partial M\cap U)=\partial\mathbb{H}^n\cap\varphi(U)$ since this open subset contains the support).

Thank you very much! It helps me alot!
